# Ajax 400 error when used inside a plugin

Tags: plugins, ajax

I'm really, really stuck.
When I run this code I get a checkbox displayed. When I click the checkbox, the javascript is run. I get "test" in the console, followed by a 400 POST error.
I can get this to work perfectly if I take it out of the plugin (and remove $this from the ajax actions), but I don't want to do that.
Please can someone point me in the right direction!

This is the code from my plugin root file

```
    require_once BUILDNEWBOAT_PATH . 'includes/BuildNewBoatPlugin.php';
    $build_boat_plugin = new BuildNewBoatPlugin();
    $build_boat_plugin->run();
```

This is inside the BuildNewBoatPlugin class

```
    public function __construct() {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'init_plugin' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_post_new_boat_form', array( $this, 'post_new_boat_form' ));
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_new_boat_form', array( $this, 'post_new_boat_form' ));
    }

    public function init_plugin() {
        wp_register_script( 'new_boat_form_script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/new_boat_form.js', array() );

        wp_localize_script( 'new_boat_form_script', 'new_boat_form_script_ajax_object',
            array(
                'ajax_url'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                //'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'new_boat_form_ajax_nonce' )
            )
        );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'new_boat_form_script');

    }

    public function post_new_boat_form(){

        print_r($_POST);
        ?>
        <p>Testing AJAX</p>
        <?php

        die();
    }

    public function run(){
        // displays an html form
    }
```

And this is my javascript file

```
    $("#boatFormStep input[type=\"radio\"]").on("change",function(){

        console.log("test");

        $.ajax({
            url: new_boat_form_script_ajax_object.ajax_url,
            data: {
                action: 'post_new_boat_form'
            },
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("test"+response)
                $("#boatFormStep").html(response);
            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log(error)
            }
        })
    })

});
```

Comment: I suspect your AJAX actions are registered late or never get registered at all, so, "This is the code from my plugin root file" - can you show the full code in that file, or where/when does the code run? Did you put the code in a function and is the function hooked into any hook? Did you get any JS errors in console? And.. have you considered using the REST API instead, which could give you a pretty URL/path like `/wp-json/my-plugin/v1/new-boat` ? (And if you're trying to create a new CPT post, then there's a core REST API endpoint for that)

Comment: If `->run()` outputs an HTML form then your first block of code must be inside a shortcode or something. Is that right? If so, you can't hook into `wp_ajax` from inside a shortcode, because that code isn't going to run on admin-ajax.php.